# How to deepen color in overlapping cells in html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have html tables and I would like to deepen color in overlapping cells.

For example when I click cell`2`,`.nextAll(':lt(5)')`method change class next `4`cells.

[image]

And then when I click `3`cells the color will change. My desired result is like below. the color of overlapping cells will change following like below formula.

`background-color: hsl(60,100%,95%);`→`background-color: hsl(60,100%,90%);`

[image]

Are there any method to realize it ?

Thanks.

```js
$(function() {
  $("td").click(function() {
    $(this).nextAll(':lt(4)').addClass('color');
  });
});
```

```css
table td {
  width: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.color {
  background-color: hsl(60,100%,95%);
}
.color2 {
  background-color: hsl(60,100%,90%);
}
.color3 {
  background-color: hsl(60,100%,85%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>6</td>
<td>7</td>
<td>8</td>
<td>9</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: please If i click on cell 5 what will be the color ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could chain `.each()` function to the `.nextAll()` results, then use `.hasClass()` to determine individually which color should be used per cell.

```js
$(function() {
  $("td").click(function() {
    $(this).nextAll(':lt(4)').each(function(i) {
  if ($(this).hasClass("color2")) {
   $(this).addClass('color3');
  }
  else if ($(this).hasClass("color")) {
   $(this).addClass('color2');
  }
  else {
   $(this).addClass('color');
  }
  
  console.log(i);
 });
  });
});
```

```css
table td {
  width: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.color {
  background-color: hsl(60,100%,95%);
}
.color2 {
  background-color: hsl(60,100%,90%);
}
.color3 {
  background-color: hsl(60,100%,85%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>6</td>
<td>7</td>
<td>8</td>
<td>9</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

It might need some tweaking to remove the uneeded classes, but I tested and seems to work as is.